# Boas práticas em uma requisição GET (API Laravel)

Tags: laravel, api

Olá, tenho uma tabela com dados de Login de usuário e essa tabela possui relação com diversas outras tabelas (FK).
Estou fazendo uma API utilizando Laravel, porém surgiu uma dúvida. Se eu fizer um GET na tabela de Login, utilizando o ID do usuário, o que é melhor como boa prática: 1. Fazer um relacionamento e quando eu dar um GET na tabela de Login, utilizando o ID do usuário, já vir os dados de todas as tabelas relacionadas.
OU 
2. Um "GET", pra cada tabela que tem o FK com o ID da tabela Login, dessa forma eu passaria um ID na requisição e cada tabela faria a "consulta" de forma individual. O que gostaria de fazer é ter uma área com os dados dessas tabela do usuário, pra que ele pudesse alterar, excluir, ler..., mas como estão distribuídas em outras tabelas, não sei o que é melhor prática ou que não seja tão pesado.

Comment: Depende da tua necessidade. Se vc quer apenas pegar os dados essenciais do usuário após o login seria uma boa prática buscar de uma única vez no banco, assim, evita requisições desnecessárias. Como vc já tem os relacionamentos, não teria o pq buscar tabela a tabela no momento do login. Na alteração dos dados, vc pode enviar um json com os dados a serem modificados e no controller validar esses dados para quais tabelas fazem parte.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, nesse caso precisarei dos dados essenciais do usuário após o login, então buscarei de única vez então, como você sugeriu.
Abraço e obrigado!

Comment: Colocarei o comentário como resposta então, caso tenha ajudado. Por gentileza, marque-a como escolhida.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depende da tua necessidade. Se vc quer apenas pegar os dados essenciais do usuário após o login seria uma boa prática buscar de uma única vez no banco, assim, evita requisições desnecessárias. Como vc já tem os relacionamentos, não teria o pq buscar tabela a tabela no momento do login. Na alteração dos dados, vc pode enviar um json com os dados a serem modificados e no controller validar esses dados para quais tabelas fazem parte.